# How to do a conditional decorator in python?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, decorator, python-decorators

Is it possible to decorate a function conditionally? For example, I want to decorate the function `foo()` with a timer function (`timeit`), but only when `doing_performance_analysis` condition is `True`, like this:

```py
    if doing_performance_analysis:
      @timeit
      def foo():
        """
        Do something, e.g. sleep, and let timeit 
        return the time it takes
        """
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
      def foo():
        time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Decorators are simply callables that return a replacement, optionally the same function, a wrapper, or something completely different. As such, you could create a conditional decorator:

```
def conditional_decorator(dec, condition):
    def decorator(func):
        if not condition:
            # Return the function unchanged, not decorated.
            return func
        return dec(func)
    return decorator
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
@conditional_decorator(timeit, doing_performance_analysis)
def foo():
    time.sleep(2)
```

The decorator could also be a class:

```
class conditional_decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, dec, condition):
        self.decorator = dec
        self.condition = condition

    def __call__(self, func):
        if not self.condition:
            # Return the function unchanged, not decorated.
            return func
        return self.decorator(func)
```

Here the `__call__` method plays the same role as the returned `decorator()` nested function in the first example, and the closed-over `dec` and `condition` parameters here are stored as arguments on the instance until the decorator is applied.

Comment: Thanks!  The comment section does not format, so I added the sample code to your original reply.  Can you pls explain why the timing function is not called?

Comment: The decorator is applied at import time, so instance variables are not being consulted at that time. You'd have to write a different decorator for that, one that inspects self when called. Out of scope for this Q and comment format. :-)

Comment: How would I use it if I want to use this on class based methods, ie Django Class based views. Over there we have to use `method_decorator`. How to make this code compatible with that?

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast: By just passing in the result of the call: `@method_decorator(conditional_decorator(timeit, doing_performance_analysis))`.

Answer (score 24):

A decorator is simply a function applied to another function. You can apply it manually:

```
def foo():
   # whatever
   time.sleep(2)

if doing_performance_analysis:
    foo = timeit(foo)
```

Answer (score 13):

How about:

```
def foo():
   ...

if doing_performance_analysis:
   foo = timeit(foo)
```

I imagine you could even wrap this into a decorator that would take a boolean flag and another decorator, and would only apply the latter if the flag is set to `True`:

```
def cond_decorator(flag, dec):
   def decorate(fn):
      return dec(fn) if flag else fn
   return decorate

@cond_decorator(doing_performance_analysis, timeit)
def foo():
   ...
```

Answer (score 4):

```
use_decorator = False

class myDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
            self.f = f

    def __call__(self):
            print "Decorated running..."
            print "Entering", self.f.__name__
            self.f()
            print "Exited", self.f.__name__


def null(a):
    return a


if use_decorator == False :
    myDecorator = null


@myDecorator
def CoreFunction():
    print "Core Function running"

CoreFunction()
```

Answer (score 3):

Blckknght's answer is great if you want to do the check every time you call the function, but if you have a setting that you can read once and never changes you may not want to check the setting every time the decorated function is called.  In some of our high performance daemons at work I have written a decorator that checks a setting file once when the python file is first loaded and decides if it should wrap it or not.

Here is a sample

```
def timed(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        return_value = f(*args, **kwargs)
        end = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        duration = end - start

        log_function_call(module=f.__module__, function=f.__name__, start=__start__, end=__end__, duration=duration.total_seconds())
    if config.get('RUN_TIMED_FUNCTIONS'):
        return wrapper
    return f
```

Assuming that log_function_call logs your call to a database, logfile, or whatever and that config.get('RUN_TIMED_FUNCTIONS') checks your global configuration, then adding the @timed decorator to a function will check once on load to see if you are timing on this server, environment, etc. and if not then it won't change the execution of the function on production or the other environments where you care about performance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

```
def timeit(method):
    def timed(*args, **kw):
        if 'usetimer' not in kw:
            return method(*args, **kw)
        elif ('usetimer' in kw and kw.get('usetimer') is None):
            return method(*args, **kw)
        else:
            import time
            ts = time.time()
            result = method(*args, **kw)
            te = time.time()
            if 'log_time' in kw:
                name = kw.get('log_name', method.__name__.upper())
                kw['log_time'][name] = int((te - ts) * 1000)
            else:
                print '%r took %2.2f ms' % \
                      (method.__name__, (te - ts) * 1000)
            return result
    return timed

def some_func(arg1, **kwargs):
    #do something here

some_func(param1, **{'usetimer': args.usetimer})
```