# how to schedule using periodic_task decorator when condition satisfies

Tags: python-2.7, celery, django-celery, celery-task, periodic-task

I have a create a decorator as below,

```
sc_status = True
class schedule_stop_dec(object):
    def __init__(self, dec, condition):
        self.decorator = dec
        self.condition = condition

    def __call__(self, func):
        if not self.condition:
            # Return the function unchanged, not decorated.
            return func
        return self.decorator(func) 

#@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=7, minute=10, day_of_week=1)
@schedule_stop_dec(periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=7, minute=10, day_of_week=1)), sc_status)
def delete_inactive_task():
    logger.log('Function triggered')
```

In the above code If i directly use the decorator @periodic_task then when it reaches the specified time function delete_inactive_task() gets triggered properlly,

But When i use scheduled_stop_dec with sc_status = True then in log I get the below message as if it gets triggered but in actual log if i check 'Function triggered' message is not there

```
[2017-03-30 10:10:00,000: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task octopus.tasks.schedule_stop.delete_inactive_task (octopus.tasks.schedule_stop.delet                               e_inactive_task)
```

Please let me know how can I control the #periodic_task decorator with specified flag.

I have tried above example using example "[how to do a conditional decorator in python 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724854/how-to-do-a-conditional-decorator-in-python-2-6)"

Comment: I don't understand for what you want to use condition? It will be calculated only one time when `celery app` starts. Could you explain your case?

Comment: Based on the flag schedule should be turned on / off. Like if the flag is off then schedule entry should not happen

Comment: Ok. You can do it without any decorators. `if condition: app.conf.beat_schedule = {...}`. Why do you want to use decorator?