# Accessing class property as decorator argument

Tags: python, class, decorator

I'm trying to apply a [conditional decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724854/how-to-do-a-conditional-decorator-in-python?answertab=active#tab-top) as described in another stackoverflow post, but I'd like the condition to be set from inside the class its being used. Instead I get a Reference error pointing that self is not defined.

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.debug = True

    @conditional_decorator(decorator, self.debug)
    def function(self):
        pass
```

I tried defining a global variable and updating it from inside the **__init__()** method but it kept its original value when called as an argument of the decorator.

```
debug = None

class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.debug = True
        global debug
        debug = self.debug

    @conditional_decorator(decorator, debug)
    def function(self):
        pass
```

The only way it worked was declaring a global variable and setting it outside of the class.

> How can I apply the value of the class property to the decorator?

Comment: btw `decorators` are applied as python reads the text of the program, not at runtime.

Comment: @quamrana: No, decorators are applied at function definition time.

Comment: Ok, when is *function definition time*?

Comment: Python function definitions are imperative - executing one generates a new function object. Decorators are applied immediately after this point. They are not and cannot be applied while Python is reading the source code; there is no function object to pass to the decorator at that point, and possibly no decorator to call either.

Comment: But surely function definition time occurs for each function *whilst* python is reading the source code (yes, just *after* reading the whole function), otherwise classes could refer to themselves by name.

Comment: @quamrana When the `def` statement is executed, at run-time.

Comment: `class` statements are *also* executed at run-time, which is why the body of a class cannot refer to the class itself, because the class does not yet exist while the body is being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update to the answer given by @Maurice Meyer which allows a member of the class to be nominated:

```
from functools import wraps

def conditional_decorator(decoration, member):
    def decorator(method):
        predecorated = decoration(method)
        @wraps(method)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            self = args[0]
            condition = getattr(self, member)
            if not condition:
                return method(*args, **kwargs)
            return predecorated(*args, **kwargs)
         return wrapper
    return decorator

#And used like this for example:
class foo:
    def __init__(self, debug):
        self.debug = debug

    @conditional_decorator(decorator, "debug")
    def function(self):
        pass

f1 = foo(True)
f1.function()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you make a decorator handle classes and arguments:

```
from functools import wraps


def conditional_decorator(param):
    def real_decorator(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            cls = args[0]
            print(cls.debug)
            print(param)
        return wrapper
    return real_decorator


class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.debug = True

    @conditional_decorator('param1')
    def function(self):
        pass



f = foo()
f.function()
```

Output:

```
True
param1
```

Answer (score 1):

The decorator should not be conditional. Rather, when the decorated function is called, it should look at `self.debug` to determine whether to use the original function or the wrapped part.

```
def conditional_decorator(dec):
    def decorator(func):
        def _(self, *args, **kwargs):
            f = func
            if self.debug:
                f = dec(f)
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return _
    return decorator


def decorator(f):
    def _(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Decorated")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return _


class foo:
    def __init__(self, debug):
        self.debug = debug

    @conditional_decorator(decorator)
    def function(self):
        print("foo stuff")

foo(True).function()
print("===")
foo(False).function()
```

outputs

```
Decorated
foo stuff
===
foo stuff
```