# toggling between two functions after x seconds

Tags: python

I have two functions, function1 and function2. I want to execute function1 for only 5 seconds, and then execute function2 for only 3 seconds and then repeat it.

I tried time.sleep() function, but it freezes entire program not executing any function.

I tried asyncio and threading, but it just executing both functions at same time.

```
def function1():
    //do something

def funtion2():
    //do something else

while True:
    function1()
    // execute function1 for 5 seconds

    function2()
    // execute function2 for 3 seconds
```

Comment: what do you mean by "execute function for x seconds"? Do you want the function executed ONCE then pause for up to x seconds, or do you want the function to repeatedly execute until x seconds pass?

Comment: I want to repeatedly execute function for x seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How precise do you need to be? Are you needing to account for the runtime of the functions themselves? That will be quite difficult.

Here's a simple approach:

```py
import time  # built-in module


def timed_execution(func, s, *args, **kwargs):
    t0 = time.time()
    while True:
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        if time.time() - t0 >= s:
            break


timed_execution(function1, 5)
timed_execution(function2, 3)
```

If you'd like to get a little more fancy, and the times your functions need to execute is always the same, you could use a decorator:

```py
import time


def timer(s):
    def timed_func(func):
        def timed_execution(*args, **kwargs):
            t0 = time.time()
            while True:
                func(*args, **kwargs)
                if time.time() - t0 >= s:
                    break
        return timed_execution
    return timed_func


@timer(5)
def function1():
    pass


@timer(3)
def function2():
    pass
```

If you want to use a decorator with a parameter for the amount of time, but only optionally, you'll need to do a bit more work. See [how to do a conditional decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724854/how-to-do-a-conditional-decorator-in-python).